# How a structure assign itself?

Tags: c, data-structures, struct

```
`#include <stdio.h>
struct uu
{  int x;
  struct uu *p;
};
struct uu fun(struct uu d)
{
  d.x *= 3;  d.p = NULL;
  return d;
} 


main()
{
  struct uu a[3] = {{5,a+2}, {8, a+1}, {11,a}};
  int j;
  for(j=0; j<3; j++) printf("%d  ", a[j].p->x);
  printf("\n");

  a[0].p--;
  a[1].p++;
  a[2].p += 2;

  for(j=0; j<3; j++) printf("%d  ", a[j].p->x);
 printf("\n");
 a[1] = fun(a[0]);
 for(j=0; j<3; j++)
 {
   printf("%d  ", a[j].x);
   if(a[j].p == NULL) break;
  }
}`
```

In this code,how this line `struct uu a[3] = {{5,a+2}, {8, a+1}, {11,a}};` assign variable to itself and how this lines

```
      a[0].p--;
      a[1].p++;
      a[2].p += 2;
```

changes adresses of structure. Basically I am so confused. Please help me. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: "*how [...] this lines changes the addres of structure?*" - it doesn't. All they are doing is changing the *values* of the `uu::p` data members.

Comment: Add the declaration of `struct uu`.

Comment: Yuo do not have any structures. It only changes the value of `p` whatever `p` is and it will not change the array or array elements addresses

Comment: Are you wondering how you can reference `a` in the initialization of itself? The address of the array is available at the time that the initialization list is evaluated.

Comment: I am edited the question. If you wish you can look again. Sorry for bothering you I am new at coding so my knowledge is very low.

Comment: @Barmar Yes sir. I still do not understand.

Answer (score 2):

Let's go through the code. Declaring the struct should be fairly straightforward.

```c
struct uu
{
    int x;
    struct uu *p;
};
```

Elements of this type will hold an integer and a pointer to something of the same type. Any object is just a chunk of memory, but we interpret the struct as some memory that first holds an integer, then maybe some padding that we don't use to align the next element, which is a pointer. That is probably not confusing.

[image]

Then for the function

```c
struct uu fun(struct uu d)
{
    d.x *= 3;
    d.p = NULL;
    return d;
}
```

notice that it takes a value of type `struct uu` as input. It is not a pointer, but a value, so if you call the function, the function gets a new variable that can hold a `struct u` and the function argument gets copied into this variable.

If we define a `struct uu` value like this:

```c
struct uu u1;
u1.x = 42;
u1.p = &u1;
```

the struct's `x` value is 42 and the struct's `p` pointer points to the struct itself. This is an arbitrary initialisation and has nothing to do with the function, I just need to put some values in there to show the function call.

Now, call `fun(u1)`. This creates the `d` variable inside the function instance, it will go somewhere on the stack, and we copy everything in `u1` into `d`. So `d.x = u1.x`  and `d.p = u1.p`.

[image]

Notice that `d.p` points to the address of `u1` and not to `d` itself. We copied the pointer, so it still has the same value. We are not recreating the same structure that `u1` has; we just put the same data in the new struct.

Notice also that `u1` and `d` are different variables. They sit in different places in memory, and they are not related in any way. So, if we modify `d`, we change the data in its memory, but we do not affect `u1` one bit.

[image]

When we return from `fun` we return a new `struct uu`, which means that we copy the data in `d` to whatever we assign to in the function call.

If, for example, we called

```c
struct uu u2 = fun(u1);
```

the result of the function, the `d` variable when we are done in the function, is copied into the struct `u2`. After that, the `d` variable is deleted; it only exists as long as the function is running.

[image]

Then we get to the `main()` function. Here, you should specify the return value; `main()` alone will technically give you the right type, but it is bad practice. You could use

```c
int main(void)
{
   ...
}
```

instead.

We define the array `a` as

```c
struct uu a[3] = {{5, a + 2}, {8, a + 1}, {11, a}};
```

Since `a` is an array of three `struct uu` it means that we have three `struct u` in consecutive memory. The first lies at address a+0, the second at a+1, and the third at a+2.

[image]

Right after we allocate the memory for `a` it is not initialised, so it is meaningless to access the data there, but the *addresses* for the different elements are there, at the offsets just listed. We can safely use those.

The initialisation, `{{5, a + 2}, {8, a + 1}, {11, a}}`, sets the values for the array (without looking at the data in it, which is garbage; we only look at the offsets to get some addresses for the `p` fields in the structs).

[image]

Then we run through the array, but we don't look at the value in each cell, we look in the cell that the `p` pointer points at.

```c
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        printf("%d  ", a[j].p->x);
    printf("\n");
```

So, when we are looking at the first cell, we are getting the value from the last cell.

[image]

When we look at the second element we are actually looking at its `x` value, because it points at itself.

[image]

and when we are looking at the last element, the pointer points at the first element in the array, so that is the `x` value we see.

[image]

When you do this

```c
    a[0].p--;
    a[1].p++;
    a[2].p += 2;
```

you move the pointer in the first element one down, from `a + 2` to `a + 1`, you move the pointer in the second element up, from `a + 1` to `a + 2`, and you move the pointer at the last element two up, from `a` to `a + 2`.

[image]

That means that when you run through the array and follow the pointers, you will get the values in `a[1]`, `a[2]` and `a[2]`.

You haven't changed the address of any structure; the pointers in them, however, points elsewhere now.

Comment: You deserve an up vote for that.

Comment: Thanks, it was my pleasure

Comment: Sir, I am very thankful for your answer. You helped me so much. And again,thank you. 
 @ThomasMailund